# Using class in Header and Cpp files in C++

Tags: c++

I am given a header file called Node.h and is defined as :

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#define MAX_RESISTORS_PER_NODE 5


class Node
{
private:

    int numRes; // number of resistors currently connected
    int resIDArray[MAX_RESISTORS_PER_NODE]; // stores the index of each resistor
    int *max_number_of_resistors;
    int *max_number_of_nodes;


public:
    Node();
   ~Node();
   // Updates resIDArray to show the resistor in position rIndex in
   // the resistor array is now connected to this node.
   // Returns true if successful
    bool addResistor (int rIndex);

   // prints the whole node
   // nodeIndex is the position of this node in the node array.
        void print (int nodeIndex);

};

#endif  /* NODE_H */
```

However, there are no arguments set for the constructors, so how do I initialize max_number_of_resistors to something that another cpp file gets? Can I make a new function in this header file called get_data(int node, int res) and in my Node.cpp file and do this:

```
#include <Node.h>
get_data(int node, int res)
{
     max_number_of_resistors = new int[res];
     max_number_of_nodes = new int[node];

}
```

and then in the file that I get the data of node and res, I can just do

```
int get_data(int x, int y)
{
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    get_data(x,y);
}
```

Comment: I would say the initialization will come from `#define MAX_RESISTORS_PER_NODE 5`

Comment: You have got to hand it to those tutors - they are imaginative.

Comment: actually the max resistors per node means the max amount of resistors attached to ONE single node is 5 but the user inputs how many nodes there are and how many resistors there are

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an *initialization list*?

```
Node()
: numRes(MAX_RESISTORS_PER_NODE)
{ ; }
```

Have you tried making another constructor with a parameter?

```
Node (unsigned int maximum_resistors)
: numRes(maximum_resistors)
{ ; }
```

Or

```
Node (unsigned int maximum_resistors)
{
   numRes = maximum_resistors;
}
```